# "Page Unresponsive" Error in Chrome when trying to GET files > 500kb

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, webkit

I am trying to get Log files in my application, and am using Ajax to do so.

The problem is that while using Chrome I constantly get 'Page Unresponsive' Errors when I try to load the files.
My application is working fine in Firefox, so I'm guessing this is a webkit issue.
I removed xhr because I heard chrome has a problem with it.

This is my code -

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: 'GET',
        url: "Logs/GetLogFile?option=" + logFile,
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            var fileData = data;
            cleanUp();
            currentlyViewedFile = logFile;
            var fileLines = fileData.split('\n');

            var htmlString = '';
            var lineCount = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < fileLines.length; i++) {
                lineCount = lineCount + 1;
                if (i == (highlightLine - 1)) {

                    htmlString += '<span id="highLoc" style="display:block"><font size="4" color="red">' + lineCount + '. ' + fileLines[i] + '</font></span>';
                }
                else {
                    htmlString += '<span class="spanClass">' + lineCount + '. ' + fileLines[i];
                }

                var combinedLine = fileLines[i];

                var isNewLogLine = false;
                var newLogLineCount = 0;
                while (((i + newLogLineCount + 1) < fileLines.length) && (isNewLogLine == false)) {
                    var NextlogLine = fileLines[i + newLogLineCount + 1].split(' ');
                    isNewLogLine = isLogLine(NextlogLine[0]);
                    if (isNewLogLine == true) {
                        break;
                    }

                    htmlString += fileLines[i + newLogLineCount + 1];
                    combinedLine += fileLines[i + newLogLineCount + 1];
                    newLogLineCount = newLogLineCount + 1
                }

                i = i + newLogLineCount;
                var logLine = combinedLine.split(' ');
                var logMsgStartIndex = combinedLine.indexOf(logLine[5]);
                var logMsg = combinedLine.substring(logMsgStartIndex);

                var obj = {
                    lineNos: lineCount,
                    date: logLine[0],
                    time: logLine[1],

                    severity: logLine[2],
                    logClassName: logLine[4],
                    logMessage: logMsg
                };
                fileArray.push(obj);

                if ((i % 1000) == 0) {

                    $("#textPlace").append(htmlString);
                    htmlString = '';
                    window.scrollTo(0, 2);
                }

            }
            fileLines = null;
            $("#fetchProgress").hide();
            $("#textPlace").append(htmlString);
            //highlight error location
            var scrollX = $("#highLoc");
            if (scrollX) {
                if (!scrollX[0]) return;
                var scrollDistance = '{ scrollTop: ' + scrollX[0].offsetTop + '}';
                var distanceInJson = eval("(" + scrollDistance + ")");
                $("#mainContentBox").animate(distanceInJson, 1);
            }
        },
        ///success function end
        fail: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        }
    });
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to deal with this issue, please let me know.

Comment: You should optimize your code to improve performance. One of the recommendation make all jQuery objects as global.

Comment: I will do that as well, but this seems to be working pretty quickly in FF for files of 5MB, whereas files of 500kb crash in Chrome. Any idea why?
Also, it crashes before it can even write the lines to the page. I'm wondering if it's an issue with the GET part.

Comment: You shouldn't have any issue with getting response content through GET request.
After getting response, There are two loops processing with response content before appending html to page, the issue would be with these loops. JavaScript execution limits varies depends on the browser engine.